Keycloak - Social IDP (Google) Logout
We've configured Keycloak to authenticate using Google-IDP and that works as expected.
Now we do have a special use case; Some of our endusers use a shared computer with a shared account, and all of them authenticate in our application using their own private Google account. The problem is, that Keycloak does not offer the possibility to logout the backing idp (That's expected in most cases, but not in this)
So we've configured a general OIDC-provider based on Google. There we can set the logout-URL to https://accounts.google.com/logout which effectively logs the user out from their Google-account, BUT not from Keycloak, so the next user will "hijack" the account of the previous user.
So basically we'd need to change the logout-flow. First logout from Keycloak and then forward to Google and logout there; Or even logout in background if that's possible.
